# Nginx uinit cors

Tags: nginx, nginx-unit

I want to handle cors on nginx unit level but I don't know how it make on nginx unit.
Example config for nginx

```
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Gc-Export-Errors';
            return 204;
        }
```

How I can do this for nginx unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Nginx Unit doesn't support functionality equal to `add_header` so if you need custom headers for `204` response it should be done using application. And configuration will looks like this:

```
{
   "match":{
      "method": "OPTIONS"
   },
   "action":{
      "proxy": "path/to/app_return_204_with_custom_headers"
   }
}
```